# Join multiple tables without overhead on the DB Server using PDO

Tags: mysql, php, amazon-rds

I have multiple tables called `light_readings`, `temp_readings`, `co2_readings` and `humidity_readings`.

The column format of the tables are as below:

- `light_readings`:

  ```
  Id, light_value, unitid, date_time
  ```
- `temp_readings`:

  ```
  Id, temp_value, unitid, date_time
  ```
- `co2_readings`:

  ```
  Id, co2_value, unitid, date_time
  ```
- `humidity_readings`:

  ```
  Id, humidity_value, unitid, date_time
  ```

I am using PDO to fetch these values to my webapp, but retrieving these using multiple SQL queries is putting too much load on my DB server. I need to get the latest readings of all the tables in just one row if possible.

I tried using UNION, but even that takes up some load on the server

```
(SELECT temp_value FROM temp_readings where unitid='SS0007' order by Id desc limit 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT humid_value FROM humid_readings where unitid='SS0007' order by Id desc limit 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT co2_value FROM co2_readings where unitid='SS0007' order by Id desc limit 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT light_value FROM light_readings where unitid='SS0007' order by Id desc limit 1)
```

Could someone assist me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rethink the schema...

Plan A:  Have `temp`, `humid`, etc, as columns in a single table.  If the date_time is the same from all the readings, then that does not need repeating.

Plan B:  Have those values in a JSON string in a single column in a single table.

Plan C:  Have a 3-column table:  (unitid, reading_name, value) and fetch the 4 values from 4 rows, but in a single `SELECT`.

In any case, `Id` is probably not needed.  The `PRIMARY KEY` can be (or start with) `(unitid, date_time)`